# use Variable on VBS

Tags: variables, vbscript, registry

I Convert a reg file to VBS commands.

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]
@=""
"VPService"="C:\\Windows\\System32\\VPService.exe"
```

but i can't use %systemroot% variable instead C:\Windows\ on this.

```
Option Explicit
Dim objShell
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Dim strComputer, ArrOfValue, oReg
const HKEY_USERS = &H80000003
const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001
const HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT = &H80000000
strComputer = "."
Set oReg=GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
objShell.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\", ""
objShell.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\", "", "REG_SZ" 'Default value
objShell.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\VPService", "C:\\Windows\\System32\\VPService.exe", "REG_SZ"
Set objShell = Nothing
WScript.Quit
```

how can use %systemroot% variable instead C:\Windows\ on this code?

Answer (score 0):

WScript.Shell can expand environment variables:

```
>> WScript.Echo CreateObject("WScript.Shell").ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%systemroot%")
>>
C:\WINDOWS
```

[Docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/subscriptions/index/dy8116cf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Make the value an [expandable string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724884%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
objShell.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run\VPService" _
  , "%SystemRoot%\\System32\\VPService.exe", "REG_EXPAND_SZ"
```